# Trying to move an element from outside to inside the viewport using translateX animation error

Tags: html, css

Trying to move an element from outside to inside the viewport using translateX, but the viewport moves to the element. You can check it here [Codepen](https://codepen.io/raveesh_travelats/pen/wGrQVO)

```
#test:target{ right:300px;  transform: translateX(-190%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-190%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-190%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-190%);
  transition-delay: .4s !important;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to hopefully fix the problem you're having, is this:

1. I removed the transition on `body`, as it would address everything inside it.
2. A container was added around the moving `div` to position (only) the moving box.
3. The transition on `.test` was only set on the `right` property, as that is the only thing changing.
4. No need for `left: 0;` when positioning an element absolute at the right (out)side of the canvas.

See my example below (in full screen) and play around with it, I did some changes to the actual movement, so please set them to your needs. Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.button {
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.test-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: lightgrey;
}
.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -20%;
  width: 270px;
  height: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  /*   transform: translateX(660%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(660%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(660%);
  -o-transform: translateX(660%); */
  transition: right .6s cubic-bezier(.22, .73, .4, 1.12);
  -webkit-transition: right .6s cubic-bezier(.22, .73, .4, 1.12);
  -moz-transition: right .6s cubic-bezier(.22, .73, .4, 1.12);
  -o-transition: right .6s cubic-bezier(.22, .73, .4, 1.12);
  background: #000;
}
#test:target {
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-190%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-190%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-190%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-190%);
  transition-delay: .4s !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"> <a href="#test">Button</a>
</div>
<div class="test-container">
  <div class="test" id="test">
  </div>
</div>
```